# How to detect if a Kubernetes application is truly "ready"?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a web app on Kubernetes that gets "spun-up" via user action. That user action triggers a python script that applies a deployment, service, and ingress. The frontend shows a spinner until the app is ready to make connections. I'm currently checking the status of the deployment and checking that the "Available" status is "True", at which point I hide the spinner and load the app.

The problem is, every once in a while, users will experience a `503: Temporarily Unavailable` error. A quick browser refresh fixes the problem, so this appears to be some sort of race condition.

My question is, why am I getting a 503 error if the deployment is marked as "Available"? Does this mean that the ingress or the service is sometimes taking longer to initialize?

I currently have the following probes on my deployment's app container:

```
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: 3000
          periodSeconds: 5
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
      livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: 3000
          periodSeconds: 5
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
```

I'm using Azure AKS and `ingress-nginx`.

Comment: Missing context: what kind of CNI do you use, what kind of Ingress?

Comment: I'm using Azure AKS and ingress-nginx

Comment: Would it be an option to check pod status next (or instead) deployment? Also ingress might not be updates instantly, so you could conclude that service is up&running only 5 seconds after successful healthcheck. HC history is also available via k8s api.

Comment: Currently I'm checking the deployment status. If the "Available" condition is "True", I'm assuming the app is ready to accept connections. 

Is there a better way to manually do a "health check" via the API?

Comment: possibly related - https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4469

Comment: Does it happen when the user deploys an app 1st time? Or during existing deploys updates (bumping images) too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For newly created deployments** check these. Both should be true, order does not matter.

- `kubectl get deployment <name> -ojson | jq ".status.availableReplicas"` equal to desired, or `>= 1`, on your preference.
- `kubectl get ingress <name> -ojson | jq ".status.loadBalancer"` is not empty. It means that ingress controller initialized for your host.

**For updated deployments** (anything that required pods to be recreated). Both should be true, order does not matter.

- `kubectl get deployment <name> -ojson | jq ".status.availableReplicas"` equal to desired.
- `kubectl get deployment <name> -ojson | jq ".status.updatedReplicas"` equal to desired.

  Ingress will already be initialized here.

Comment: Is it not sufficient to check `.conditions` for `type="Available"`?

Comment: It won't include ingress status for sure. And I'm not sure about the update flow, it might be available all the time because there will be healthy pods all the time, but with an older version or mixed old/new at the same time.

Comment: What I posted is 1. Guaranteed ready to accept traffic. 2. Guaranteed all versions are updated and ready to accept traffic.